# Topological spaces with Lebesgue covering dimension 1

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

We know that all connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$( with the usual topology) has no empty interior. I would like to know if this fact remains true for a general 
 connected topological space with the Lebesgue covering dimension equal 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C \subset [0,1]$ is the Cantor set, how about $([0,1] \times C) \cup (\{0\} \times [0,1])$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?  It's connected and one-dimensional, but $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: @ NateEldredge The real line has a basis formed by connected open sets, while your set does not have a such basis. Maybe with this additional assumption (that is, the topological space has a basis formed by connected sets),  the statement is true?